# When was fire breathing banned from Paris Métro?

Tags: france, transportation, paris

I see on [youtube](https://youtu.be/-h__d26XcGw?t=640) that [fire breathing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_breathing) was allowed or  tolerated in [Paris Métro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_M%C3%A9tro) in 1982. However, I have never seen any fire breather between 2000 and now. When was fire breathing banned from Paris Métro?

Comment: Are such laws made public on any government archive site?

Comment: Was it actually banned?  Or did it just go out of fashion?

Comment: @GorttheRobot I'm guessing banned because I have seen a fair number of fire breathers on the street (e.g. in front of Notre Dame).